# VS2013's rename refactoring doesn't work correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, refactoring, rename

I don't know, if this is a known issue, because I couldn't find anything regarding to my problem.
When I discovered the problem I tested it on this simple sample code

```
using System;
namespace Test {
    public static class Test {
        public static byte TestProp = 0;
        public static void Main () {
            TestProp = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I selected `TestProp` (in line 4) and replaced it with `AnotherTestProp`. Normally there pops up a little menu under the edited name. In this menu I can click on `Rename "TestProp" to "AnotherTestProp"` and it renamed all occurences of `TestProp` to `AnotherTestProp`.

Since the installation of **Visual Studio 2013 Express**'s Update 2 this feature doesn't work anymore. When I want to rename all occurences, VS renames the edited name back into its old name. I have to rename all occurences by hand.

Does anyone else get this problem? Is this a known issue? Is there a fix for it?